# Check if a string consists only of letters and / or hyphens with matches?

Tags: java, string, task

Good evening from Cologne.

In a programming task I have to check if the given string consists **only** of **letters** and / or **hyphens**. Now I have an approach with **matches**. In the test of the word: "test-test-test" my code gives me false. It should be true. Do you know where the problem lies with me? Did I misunderstand at matches? I thank you in advance. Beautiful evening!

```
    public class Zeichenketten {


    public static boolean istName(String a) {

        if (a.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") || a.matches("[-]+")) {
            return true;
        }

            else {
            return false;
            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: Moin Moin ;-) Code not written with english words just ... looks ... weird ... (I'm  a native btw).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @StefanHanke. But on my University the exercises are on german. :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you're checking whether it's *all* letters, or *all* hyphens. You just need to check whether it matches *letters or hyphens*:

```
public static boolean istName(String a) {
    return a.matches("[a-zA-Z-]+");
}
```

The `-` at the end means "a hyphen" rather than "part of a range".

Note the simplification away from if/else - any time you write `if (condition) return true; else return false;` you should just write `return condition;` for simplicity.

Comment: @assylias: Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't match your test string because [String.matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) method returns true only when whole string matches by regex pattern. In first case: `[a-zA-Z]+` you don't match because you have `-` symbol in the string, in second where pattern is `[-]+` you don't match because you have letters in string.

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong condition. 
You must create one regular expression and create good patern.

I recomended this page: https://regex101.com/ for test online regular expression.

Try this for you example:

```
   public static boolean istName(String a) {

        if (a.matches("[a-zA-Z-]+")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

the hyphen has the ASCII value of 45, and you know that a string is an array of characters. So you have a loop to check each character of the given string, if it finds one with the ASCI 45, return true, else return false.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. "0123-1234" does contain '-', but shouldn't match. (There's no need to worry about what the ASCII value is, either.)